# jQuery functions being skipped after animation

Tags: jquery, function

I have the following piece of code which is being run from a click function. For some reason the the part that is animating down to 100px never runs the `console.log` or `my_function()` it skips anything you place in there. The part that animates upto 200px all runs fine. What gives?

```
if($(this).hasClass('open'))
{ 
  $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
  $(this).animate({'width': '100px'}, {queue:false, duration:150, easing: 'linear'}).delay(160, function (){
    //Nothing in here ever get run??
    console.log('closed');
    my_function();
  });
}
else
{
  $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
  $(this).animate({'width': '200px'}, {queue:false, duration:200, easing: 'linear'}).delay(210, function (){
    console.log('opened');
    my_function();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.fn.delay` does not have a callback parameter.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I was thinking this too - but he said the else statement works. But I can't sort out why that would ever work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. jsFiddle coming soon

Comment: Here's a fiddle. It does fire one console.log http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/tRUBr/

Comment: Based on the core(line 2103 - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) it shouldn't be able to accept a callback.

Comment: Well +1 for effort KevinB. @CraigWard - It shouldn't work and it actually only works for the first click to close. Subsequent ones fail. One could try and find out exactly why by looking through core code, but I don't think its worth the effort.

Comment: @mrtsherman Ah, i think know why it works. the $.fn.queue method accepts 2 parameters: a string, and a function. When you instead pass two functions, the function passed in as a callback is converted to a string, creating a queue called "undefinedqueue" which then instantly calls it's callback function, resulting in the console.log. However, that doesn't explain why it only works once.

Comment: Ah, it does actually explain why it only works once. We created a new queue, but the `next` method was never called within it, so the queue never progresses.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback to `.animate`, instead of trying to use `.delay`. Try this:

```
$(this).animate({'width': '100px'}, 150, function (){
    console.log('closed');
    my_function();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my previous example had a syntax error. Edited the answer with a simpler solution.

Comment: Still not logging anything to the console when closing :/

Comment: There must be something else on your code causing an error. See this [very simple example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mYXHp/), it always logs to the console after closing (even if it's already closed)

Comment: going to revisit my code, I agree it must be something external.